# Relationship between ST-Path Ideals and ST-Cut Ideals?

Tags: graph-theory, ideals, st-connectivity

Topic: st-connectivity, st-cut ideals and path ideals of a graph

**My Lemma:** None of the st-cut-monomials vanish iff there is at least a st-path that does not vanish.

*Example*

> ST-cuts: {{1,3,5,6},{1,3,7},{1,4,5,6},{1,4,7},{2,3,5,6},{2,3,7},{2,4,5,6},{2,4,7}}
>
> ST-paths: {{1,2},{3,4},{5,7},{6,7}}
>
> [image]
>
> ST-cut-monomials: $$\{\{x_1x_3x_5x_6\},\{x_1x_3x_7\},\{x_1x_4x_5x_6\},\{x_1x_4x_7\},\{x_2x_3x_5x_6\},\{x_2x_3x_7\},\{x_2x_4x_5x_6\},\{x_2x_4x_7\}\}$$
>
> ST-path-monomials: $$\{\{x_1x_2\},\{x_3x_4\},\{x_5x_7\},\{x_6x_7\}\}$$
>
> Ideals by the cut monomials and by the path monomials, respectively,
>
> $\begin{align}
> \langle C_{all}\rangle = \langle \text{cut monomials not vanishing}\rangle &= \tiny{\langle x_1x_3x_5x_6-1,x_1x_3x_7-1,x_1x_4x_5x_6-1,x_1x_4x_7-1,x_2x_3x_5x_6-1,x_2x_3x_7-1,x_2x_4x_5x_6-1,x_2x_4x_7-1\rangle } \\
> \langle P_{all}\rangle = \langle \text{path monomials not vanishing}\rangle &= \langle x_1x_2 -1,x_3x_4 -1,x_5x_7-1,x_6x_7 -1 
> \rangle \end{align}$
>
> and $\langle C_{all}\rangle =\langle P_{all}\rangle$ is equivalent to `None of cut monomials vanish iff none of path monomials vanish.` so
>
> $\langle C_{all}\rangle = \langle x_1x_2 -1\rangle$
>
> $\langle C_{all}\rangle = \langle x_3x_4 -1\rangle$
>
> $\langle C_{all}\rangle = \langle x_5x_7-1\rangle$
>
> $\langle C_{all}\rangle = \langle x_6x_7 -1\rangle$
>
> where any of four expressions is sufficient that Out-In are connected.

**How to express the duality between cuts and paths in terms of st-cut-ideals and st-path-ideals?**